# Recording Specific User Event

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

We have a non-profit website that has an ad blocker detect on it and need the ability to determine how many times the "You Have a Ad Blocker running" appears.

Basically, when an ad blocker is detected, I run JS code to display a banner asking they turn it off (same message we all see). I only fire the code if a ad blocker is detected. We want to capture how many times the ad blocker is hit as it impacts our donations and we need to account for it.

I control the message display in JS and am wondering if something like Google Analytics would be the way to capture this?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: are you asking if it is possible, to use Google Analytics to count how many times Ad Blocker banner apears? Or how many times user clicks on it? If yes: both are possible through [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Comment: Hi @RaV, yes. The banner only appears in certain circumstances. Was looking at the link you sent and that looks very promising. If I were to wrap that in a JS block, hit only when conditions are met, would it only fire at that point, or does it fire every time the page is loaded regardless?

Comment: it fires when you want it to fire ;) You can use JS to achive measurement you described. I've added proper answer, since I've got your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure it with [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) feature.
Events can be send to Google Analytics with any action of an user - not only page view, but on click, element visibility or basically on any condition you specify with the use of JS.

You can put event tracking straight into your code, but be sure to check out [Google Tag Manager](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/tag-manager/) tool. It is widely used in digital analytics - helps keep code cleaner, and allows non-developers to easy implement further measurements. You can also set event tracking with the use of JS in GTM.